# Undefined AJAX error

Tags: php, xml, ajax

I had to come here to see if anyone has ever had an error where there isn't one in JQuery AJAX.

I am returning xml and it all works fine on one server but not on another. The response code in Firebug is 404 but when I open it up both the response and xml are showing my xml. The success is not firing, and the error is showing as undefined.

The working version is here http://www.write-about-property.com/test/

and the unworking is here http://ukfloorsanding.com/

Answer (score 2):

Ajax.php does not exist on the not working website.

Comment: I know panto season is past, but, OH Yes it Does http://ukfloorsanding.com/wp-content/themes/gallweb_gen_child/ajax.php